# Applying a method with no return value to each element of a list

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Is there a way to use methods with no return value such as random.shuffle in a list comprehension?

```
>>> import pprint
>>> import random
>>> 
>>> L = [ random.shuffle(range(5)) for x in range(5)]
>>> 
>>> print L
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

This is the for loop that applies the random.shuffle method to each item of my list:

```
>>> L = [ range(5) for x in range(5) ]
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> for element in L:
...     random.shuffle(element)
... 
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[2, 0, 3, 1, 4],
 [2, 0, 1, 4, 3],
 [4, 1, 3, 0, 2],
 [1, 2, 4, 3, 0],
 [1, 3, 0, 2, 4]]
```

I can use map, which as a side effect shuffles the original list but returns a list of `None`

```
>>> L = [ range(5) for x in range(5) ]
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> map(random.shuffle, L)
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[3, 0, 4, 1, 2],
 [2, 3, 0, 1, 4],
 [2, 3, 1, 4, 0],
 [4, 2, 0, 3, 1],
 [1, 3, 0, 2, 4]]
```

as does using the list comprehension with shuffle:

```
>>> L = [ range(5) for x in range(5) ]
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
 [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]]
>>> L1 = [ random.shuffle(x) for x in L ]
>>> pprint.pprint(L1)
[None, None, None, None, None]
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[1, 4, 0, 2, 3],
 [0, 4, 1, 3, 2],
 [2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
 [4, 1, 0, 2, 3],
 [2, 0, 4, 3, 1]]
```

Many questions and answers on stack overflow already point out that using map or a lc for the side effect is bad practice. I was wondering if there's any correct way to use a method with no return value in a list comprehension.

Is writing a method to wrap the non-returning method the only way:

```
>>> def shuffled(L):
...     ret_val = L[:]
...     random.shuffle(ret_val)
...     return ret_val
... 
>>> L = [ shuffled(range(5)) for x in range(5)]
>>> pprint.pprint(L)
[[2, 1, 0, 4, 3],
 [4, 0, 3, 1, 2],
 [4, 2, 3, 0, 1],
 [1, 0, 4, 2, 3],
 [2, 4, 3, 0, 1]]
>>>
```

Comment: I like your `shuffled` method, go with that in a list comprehension!

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects

Comment: The question isn't well formed because *there is no such thing as "a [function] with no return value"*. `None` is just as much a "return value" as anything else, which is why it appears in the list comprehension when used that way. The advice about not using list comprehensions is all that can really be said; the existing code in OP is already "correct" in that it calls the appropriate functions and has the appropriate side effects. It also produces a list of `None` values, which can simply be ignored.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

No - list comprehensions are meant to be use with functions having return values. It's how their semantics [are defined](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> List comprehensions provide a concise
>   way to create lists without resorting
>   to use of map(), filter() and/or
>   lambda. The resulting list definition
>   tends often to be clearer than lists
>   built using those constructs. Each
>   list comprehension consists of an
>   expression followed by a for clause,
>   then zero or more for or if clauses.
>   The result will be a list resulting
>   from evaluating the expression in the
>   context of the for and if clauses
>   which follow it.

Having read this, it should be clear that "a list comprehension from a function having no return value" is an oxymoron.

Just use a `for` loop for something "one off":

```
import random
L = []
for x in range(5):
  l = range(5)
  random.shuffle(l)
  L.append(l)
```

Clean and simple. Your `shuffled` function is also just fine, and *can* be used in a list comprehension.

Answer (score 8):

Eli is quite right. But I'd go for something more concise:

```
import random

L = [range(5) for each in xrange(5)]
for each in L:
    random.shuffle(each)
```

**[edit]**

OTOH you could use `random.sample()`:

```
from random import sample

xr = xrange(5)
L = [sample(xr, 5) for each in xr]
```